# Material ui auto complete out of position if open

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-design, material-ui

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
  <AutoComplete
    open
    animated={false}
    filter={(searchText, key) => !key || key.includes(searchText)}
    autoFocus
    dataSource={["1", "2", "3"]}
  />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

[image: Edit 31qj76v9xq]

If I want the list of results to be shown on load, the search results will be wrongly positioned at the top left corner. Any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a working snippet?

Comment: @A.J I did...https://codesandbox.io/s/31qj76v9xq

Comment: anchorEl is probably never set [source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.js#L216-L222). I think only componentWillMount will fire and not componentWillReceiveProps. So seems like a bug with the lib. You can set a timeout and open it in componentDidMount or something. [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1rk657vmxq)